# Error: com.mongodb.MongoCursorNotFoundException: while reading from MongoDB into Spark

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to read a collection in MongoDB in Spark with 234 million records. I want only 1 field.

```
case class Linkedin_Profile(experience : Array[Experience])
case class Experience(company : String)

val rdd = MongoSpark.load(sc, ReadConfig(Map("uri" -> mongo_uri_linkedin)))
val company_DS = rdd.toDS[Linkedin_Profile]()
val count_udf = udf((x: scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray[String]) => {x.filter( _ != null).groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size)})
val company_ColCount = company_DS.select(explode(count_udf($"experience.company")))
comp_rdd.saveAsTextFile("/dbfs/FileStore/chandan/intermediate_count_results.csv")
```

The job runs for 1 hour with half of jobs completed but after that it gives an error

```
com.mongodb.MongoCursorNotFoundException: 
Query failed with error code -5 and error message 
'Cursor 8962537864706894243 not found on server cluster0-shard-01-00-i7t2t.mongodb.net:37017' 
on server cluster0-shard-01-00-i7t2t.mongodb.net:37017
```

I tried changing the configuration with below, but to no avail.

```
System.setProperty("spark.mongodb.keep_alive_ms", "7200000")
```

Please suggest how to read this large collection.

Answer (score 1):

The config property `park.mongodb.keep_alive_ms` is meant to control the life of the client. See docs [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/configuration/#cache-configuration).

The issue you're experiencing seems to be related to server-side configuration. According to what's documented [on this issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-8188):

> By specifing the cursorTimeoutMillis option, administrators can configure mongod or mongos to automatically remove idle client cursors after a specified interval. The timeout applies to all cursors maintained on a mongod or mongos, may be specified when starting the mongod or mongos and may be modified at any time using the setParameter command.

So, try starting your `mongod` daemon with specified `cursorTimeoutMillis`, such as:

```
mongod --setParameter cursorTimeoutMillis=10800000
```

This command tries to instruct the server to keep cursors valid for 3 hours.

Although this may in theory get rid of the annoyance, it is still a good idea to get the reads to complete faster. You might want to look into limiting the dataset sitting in collections to what you really want to load into Spark. There may be many options to tune the read speed worth looking into.

Answer (score 1):

Yes，By specifing the cursorTimeoutMillis option, you can avoid this.
But,if you are not the administrators, you can cache the MongoRdd by Action first, then do something in spark env.